# Android In App Billing - Unable to remove PurchaseData from account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am testing adding in app billing to an app I'm developing and have found that I'm unable to use the same device more than once for testing as the device reports that the purchase has already happened.

So far 1) I have refunded the purchase from my Google console, 2) Cleared data cache and app data, 3) Cleared Google Play Services cache, 4) Cleared Google Play Store cache.

Can anyone help with how to remove the purchase information from my devices?

If this question has already been answered please point me to it as I have not found a solution that actually works.

Comment: Maybe using another google account will works!

Comment: You can change the product id on playstore to check and also check signin to playstore account with  another google account

Comment: GmloMalo and user2231938 - I have tried using a different account already but the purchase seems to be tied to my device(s).  I really don't want to add a new product id as I'm getting ready to publish my app.